# Is there a way to require certain configuration to be provided in a Nuxt 3 config?

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxt3

When setting up a [Nuxt 3 config](https://nuxt.com/docs/getting-started/configuration#environment-variables-and-private-tokens), is there a way to specify which values are required vs optional, such that if a required configuration value is missing the application won't start and will provide a helpful error message?

I know I can provide default values, which is helpful for optional configuration, but it is nice to be explicit at startup about which configuration as required at minimum for the application to function.